# Remove last 2 characters of string if set variable is 2 digits long

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to remove the last two digits if the set variable added is 2 digits long

eg. 000%i% may equal 0001 or 00015 where as I need for it to be 0015 not 00015

I then had to make almost redundant and unnecessary code to bypass this.

Please ignore the bad format, this is basically my first try at scripting.

See Below Code:

```
@echo off

set brokendriver=Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
set brokendriver1= Random Name

set /a i=0
set /a max=9
set /a Limit=30

:start

IF %i%==%Limit% (Echo Driver Not Found
pause
exit)

IF %i% LEQ %max% (
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\000%i% /v DriverDesc`) DO (
    set drivername=%%A %%B
    )
) ELSE (
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\00%i% /v DriverDesc`) DO (
    set drivername=%%A %%B
    )
  )

IF "%brokendriver%"=="%drivername%" (GOTO:next)
IF "%brokendriver1%"=="%drivername%" (GOTO:next)

set /a i+=1
GOTO:start

:next
IF %i% LEQ %max% (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\000%i% /v PnPCapabilities`) DO (
    set driveroldvalue=%%A %%B )
    REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\000%i% /v PnPCapabilities /t REG_DWORD /d 24 /f
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\000%i% /v PnPCapabilities`) DO (
    set drivernewvalue=%%A %%B
    )
) ELSE (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\00%i% /v PnPCapabilities`) DO (
    set driveroldvalue=%%A %%B )
    REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002bE10318}\00%i% /v PnPCapabilities /t REG_DWORD /d 24 /f
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\00%i% /v PnPCapabilities`) DO (
    set drivernewvalue=%%A %%B
    )
)

Echo Driver Name: "%drivername%"
Echo Driver Old Value: %driveroldvalue%
Echo Driver New Value: %drivernewvalue%

pause
```

Comment: Take a look at the [sub-string expansion syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I would solve this:

```
@echo off

set brokendriver=Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter
set brokendriver1= Random Name

set /a i=10000
set /a Limit=10030

:start

IF %i%==%Limit% (Echo Driver Not Found
pause
exit)

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\%i:~1% /v DriverDesc`) DO (
    set drivername=%%A %%B
)
```

The i variable have an initial value of `10000`, so you just need to get the value of i after the first digit, that is `%i:~1%` to get a number with four digits always. The increment of `i` works in the same way and it is only necessary to change the `Limit` from `30` to `10030`.

Comment: Very clever, Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to tell from all that code where you are trying to put what.

Tip: After `@echo off`, put a line

```
setlocal
```

which will ensure that any changes you make to the environment are discarded when the batch ends. That way, you don't have stale data ffrom a previous run while you're debugging.

As for getting just the last `n` digits, you can use `%var:~-n%` where `var` contains your string.

If you are using numerics, then

```
set /a var+=1000000
```

will make sure your variable is 7-digits long (provided `var` is originally 0..999999) and then `%var:~-5%` will provide the last 5 digits. Mix and match to suit your situation.

---

For example

```
set /a paddedi=1000000+i 

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3*" %%A IN (
 `REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\%paddedi:~-4% /v DriverDesc`
 ) DO set drivername=%%A %%B
```

replaces the entire second `if` statement, padding the value of `i` (great name for a variable!) and then using the last 4 characters of the resulting padded variable.

Comment: Apologies, see Second IF statement that is basically duplicated bar 000%i% and 00%i%

Comment: Very clever, Thank you for that